# Saved image in paint application is not sharing & showing "Sharing failed, please try again later toast is showing"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, file-sharing, share-intent

"Sharing failed, please try again." toast is showing on clicking on the apps to share the image. The image is saving in my phone but it can't be shared. Made the xml directory & new resource file path.xml , added this to the mainfest file & created fun for sharing the image.But it is not working.

**Manifest file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.nandini.android.drawdoodle">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DrawDoodle">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:authorities="com.nandini.android.fileprovider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/path"/>
        </provider>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**path.xml file in xml directory**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path
        name="Captured"
        path="Android/data/com.nandini.android.drawdoodle/files"/>
</paths>
```

**MainActivity.kt file**

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
private var share_btn:ImageButton?=null

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            share_btn=findViewById(R.id.share_btn)
        
        fun isStorageAllowed():Boolean{
            val result=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            return result==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
    
        fun requestStoragePermission(){
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                showRationaleDialog("Draw Doodle","Draw Doodle requires access to External Storage.")
            }else{
                requestPermission.launch(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            }
        }
    
    private fun getBitmapFromView(view:View): Bitmap? {
        val returnedBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width,view.height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas=Canvas(returnedBitmap)
        val bgDrawable=view.background
        if(bgDrawable !=null){
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas)
        }else{
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
        }
        view.draw(canvas)
        return returnedBitmap
    }
        private suspend fun saveBitmapFile(mBitmap: Bitmap?):String{
            var result =""
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                if(mBitmap !=null){
                    try {
                        val bytes=ByteArrayOutputStream()
                        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,bytes)
    
                        val f = File(externalCacheDir?.absoluteFile?.toString()+ File.separator+"Draw_Doodle"+System.currentTimeMillis()/1000+".png")
    
                        val fo=FileOutputStream(f)
                        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
                        fo.close()
    
                        result=f.absolutePath
    
                        runOnUiThread{
                            cancelProgressDialog()
                            if(result.isNotEmpty()){
                                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"File saved successfully : $result",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                share_btn?.setOnClickListener{shareImage(result)}
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Something went wrong.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (e:Exception){
                        result=""
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    
        private fun shareImage(result:String){
             MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, arrayOf(result),null){
                 path,uri->
                 val shareIntent=Intent()
                 shareIntent.action=Intent.ACTION_SEND
                 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri)
                 shareIntent.type="image/png"
                 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share"))
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Much too much irrelevant code for sharing a file. Ten code lines would do. Please edit your post.

Comment: Edited the post. Please answer.

Comment: For what reason are you posting a complete manifest file? And xml paths file? Also requests for storage permissions seem irrelevant.

Comment: `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, arrayOf(result),null){
                 path,uri->` I think that `uri` will be null. Check before use.